# Balance ragged and hyphenation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, typography, hyphenation

From Beautiful Evidence:

[image]

Each paragraph is left-justified but neither excessively hyphenated nor ragged on the right side.

The tufte-book class seems to be too ragged. 
How can I configure the balance between "raggedness" and hyphenation in the tufte-book class?

It seems to use

```
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{\z@ plus 0.08\hsize}
```

but I don't know if this is the right variable to modify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the correct variable to play with.  It is allow lines to be up to 8% shorter than standard.  Try reducing it via e.g.

```
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 0.02\hsize}
```

for a percentage (here 2%) of the line length or

```
\setlength{\RaggedRightskip}{0pt plus 1em}
```

for an absolute possible shortfall.  For the `tufte` classes this change needs to be made in the preamble.

See the [documentation of the `ragged2e` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e?lang=en) for further information.

Here are a couple of samples, first with a short fall of `1em`:

[image: Sample one]

and then as standard

[image: Sample two]

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum}       %Dummy text in Latin
\usepackage[latin]{babel} %Correct hyphenation patters

\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 1em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any attempt to use \setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip} in Lualatex (e.g. in above MWE with babel removed)  leads either to a latex system crash or \RaggedRightRightskip undefined error. The macro is still mentioned in the manual.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I can't reproduce that; the example runs fine for me under lualatex.

Comment: My bad -- actually it is the tufte-handout. The above MWE does not compile -- probably a previous version of tufte-handout loaded \usepackage{ragged2e} but the current version does not (or maybe just under Lua?). Adding \usepackage{ragged2e} to the above MWE corrects the problem.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn The newest version of tufte-handout I can find is 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 (both ctan and github) and the above code works with that in pdf- and lualatex.